# NoSuchElementException when iterating

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

This code runs perfectly fine the first time the loop goes around but when I come to iterate over it again (after the full program is executed). It throws a `NoSuchElementException`, nowhere in my code do I close any `Scanner` at all so what could be the problem?

I should also mention the complier gives me the line where the method in which this loop is called and the line is : `l = scan.nextInt();`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int l;
do {
System.out.println("Please Select...:");
System.out.println("1. for ...");
l = scan.nextInt();
}
while (l < 0 || l > 4);
```

My variable is the letter "L" in lower case, just so no one gets confused.

Comment: What do you mean by *after the full program is executed*?

Comment: @assylias I mean that, I have a bunch of methods in a switch statement that I would like to put in a loop. So I used a Do While loop and it it all works fine the first time you execute the code but then it throws this exception when this method is called.

Comment: Your code as described in your question works fine. You should post a short but complete (i.e. compilable) example that replicates your issue to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` is thrown when there is no data in the input. That has to be the case in your code, but as long as you do not provide the complete example it is hard to find any solution. My first suggestion would be to check if there is any data  in the input using `hasNextInt()` method and invoke `nextInt()` only if value returned by first function was `true`.